# apache.wicketでのdatabaseを使ったサンプルを教えて下さい。

Tags: java, framework

eclipseを使って、apache.wicketの勉強を始めたのですが、サンプルが少なくてよく分かりません。
特にdatabaseを使ったものはほとんどありません。
どなたかご教授して頂けたらありがたいのですが。
(V.1.4.23)

Answer (score 2):

### データベースを使用したサンプルについて

JDBCやHibernate等を使用してデータベースにアクセスすることになりますので、想定されているフレームワークを記載されると、より詳細な回答が得られるかもしれません。

Wicket 6ですが、MyBatisを使用した場合のサンプルであれば見つかりました。
http://tsukaby.com/tech_blog/archives/81

### 他のサンプルや資料について

データベースとは直接関係ありませんが、WicketのHPの [Example](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/) や [User Guide](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/) 、githubの [wicket-examples](https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples) が参考になるかと思います。

### サンプルコード

データベースを使用する際のイメージがつかみやすい様に、Spring + Hibernateを使用した場合のイメージを下記に記載しておきます。(Wicket v7.0.0-M4 / JDK 1.8)

`userDao.list()`でユーザー一覧をDBから取得して表示し、"add"や"delete"がクリックされた時に`userDao.save()`と`userDao.delete()`でデータベースへ追加・削除を行い画面を更新しています。

何かの参考になれば幸いです。

- UserPage.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
      <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>User List</h1>
      <form wicket:id="form">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" wicket:id="name" />
        <label>e-mail</label>
        <input type="email" wicket:id="email" />
        <input type="submit" value="add" wicket:id="addUser" />
      </form>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>e-mail</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody wicket:id="view">
          <tr wicket:id="list">
            <td wicket:id="id"></td>
            <td wicket:id="name"></td>
            <td wicket:id="email"></td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" wicket:id="deleteUser">delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- UserPage.java

  ```
  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
  import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink;
  import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
  import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.*;
  import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.*;
  import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.*;
  import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.*;
  import org.apache.wicket.model.CompoundPropertyModel;
  import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
  import org.apache.wicket.util.value.ValueMap;

  import dao.UserDao;
  import dto.User;

  public class UserPage extends WebPage {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @SpringBean
      private UserDao userDao;

      public UserPage() {
          final List<User> users = userDao.list();

          final WebMarkupContainer view = new WebMarkupContainer("view");
          view.add(
              new PropertyListView<User>("list", users) {
                  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                  @Override
                  protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> item) {
                      item.add(new Label("id"));
                      item.add(new Label("name"));
                      item.add(new Label("email"));

                      item.add(new AjaxLink("deleteUser") {
                          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                          @Override
                          public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                              final User u = item.getModelObject();

                              userDao.delete(u);
                              users.remove(u);

                              target.add(view);
                          }
                      });
                  }
              }
          );
          add(view.setOutputMarkupId(true));

          final Form<ValueMap> form = new Form<>("form", new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new ValueMap()));
          form.add(new TextField<String>("name").setType(String.class));
          form.add(new EmailTextField("email"));
          form.add(new AjaxButton("addUser", form) {
              private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

              @Override
              protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> f) {
                  super.onSubmit(target, f);

                  final ValueMap values = form.getModelObject();

                  final User u = new User();
                  u.setName((String)values.get("name"));
                  u.setEmail((String)values.get("email"));
                  userDao.save(u);
                  users.add(u);

                  // Clear input value.
                  values.put("name", "");
                  values.put("email", "");

                  // Update view.
                  target.add(view);
                  target.add(form);
              }
          });
          add(form);
      }
  }
  ```
- User.java

  ```
  package dto;

  import java.io.Serializable;

  import javax.persistence.Column;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
  import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.Table;

  @Entity
  @Table(name="User")
  public class User implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @Column(name="id")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Integer id;
      private String name;
      private String email;

      public User() {}

      public Integer getId() {
          return id;
      }
      public void setId(Integer id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }

      public String getEmail() {
          return email;
      }
      public void setEmail(String email) {
          this.email = email;
      }

      /* (non-Javadoc)
       * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
       */
      @Override
      public String toString(){
          return "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email;
      }
  }
  ```